# Concat videos too slow using Python MoviePY

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am joining 50s or more videos of 1,2,3 minutes using MoviePY but it's giving me 20 hours, even though I have 64 GB of ram, i7 and GTX 670, not top of range yet reasonable. Is there anyway I can speed this process up ?

```
padding = 10 # padding option
video_clips = [VideoFileClip(video_dir + video) for video in os.listdir(video_dir)]
video_fx_list = [video_clips[0]]

idx = video_clips[0].duration - padding
for video in video_clips[1:]:
video_fx_list.append(video.set_start(idx).crossfadein(padding))
idx += video.duration - padding

final_video = CompositeVideoClip(video_fx_list)
final_video.write_videofile(video_dir + 'myoutfile.mp4', fps=24)
```

I don't need original audio these clips have, would removing it going to speed things up ? not sure how to remove audio though/

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can specify a number of `threads` in `write_videofile`  . It will significantly speed up the export by using all cores of your machine.

```
final_video.write_videofile(video_dir + 'myoutfile.mp4', threads = 8, fps=24)
```

**Aditionnal notes:**

- You could `resize` all videos to a lower resolution (e.g. 720p)
- Decreasing `fps` makes also a big difference, but 24 fps is already well optimized
- Moviepy uses only the CPU to render the video. Consider to upgrade your CPU or run your program on cloud services (e.g. Amazon AWS, Google Cloud, MS Azure..) for better performance

Answer (score 9):

Python isn't efficient when it comes to video editing.

If you're using MoviePY, have a look at
https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/ffmpeg.html
(maybe use the github dev version, which is more stable)

You have some functions that perform direct calls to ffmpeg:
https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_tools.py
And are therefore extremely efficient, for simple tasks such as yours

Comment: FFmpeg maybe good, but I don't know why it's so difficult to work with, I am still trying to find a way to concat all videos in a directory with transition effects using FFmpeg

Comment: this is actually the correct answer. https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/ffmpeg.html have it all. ```moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools.ffmpeg_merge_video_audio``` is the one OP is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I use cuda accelerate with ffmpeg parser `-vcodec h264_nvenc`.
It's work for me , on Win10 and ffmpeg 4.2.3 version, NVIDA GPU.
(u should find the **specified-ffmpeg-parser** for your GPU.)
it will speeded up 5~10 times.
and i have implemented [cut clips, concat videos, concat with crossfade, add bgm] with cuda...

```
'''
here is concat videos with cuda accelerate.
so you can subclip the video fragment and clip them, then concat with others.
'''


import os

def save_flist(files):
    f_data = 'file \'' + '\'\nfile \''.join(files) + '\''
    print(f_data)

    f_list = 'list.txt'
    with open(f_list, 'w', encoding='gbk') as f:
        f.write(f_data)
    return f_list

video_path = r'E:\py\mkv\\'
os.chdir(video_path)

output_path = 'output.mkv'

files = ['1.mkv', '2.mkv', '3.mkv', '4.mkv']
print(files)        # your video_names.

f_list = save_flist(files)

call = f'ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i {f_list} -c copy {output_path} -y'         # only supporte the same video_format, copy and not recode.

call = f'ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i {f_list} -vcodec h264_nvenc {output_path} -y'    # cuda accelerate.

print(call)

os.system(call)

os.remove(f_list)
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the best speedup you need to use `ffmpeg-tools` from `moviepy`. Here is an example:

```py
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_merge_video_audio
# printing logs can be a bottleneck sometimes, so we put ffmpeg_ouput=False
# and logger = None
# you can change video codec(vcodec) or audio codec (acodec) as per your need
ffmpeg_merge_video_audio(video_path,
                         audio_path,
                         output_path,
                         vcodec='copy',
                         acodec='copy',
                         ffmpeg_output=False,
                         logger=None)
```

And also I would suggest it to run in a `standalone process` (other than main process/thread). You can easily do it with `multiprocessing` module in python.

But even if you want to stick with `final_video.write_videofile()`, I would say, pass `verbose=False` and `logger=None` to get you some speedups in I/O. And also use `threads=as you want`. Like below:

```py
final_video.write_videofile(video_dir + 'myoutfile.mp4', 
                           fps=24, 
                           verbose=False,
                           logger=None,
                           threads=32)
```

I am actually not sure why this is so slow as under the hood this `write_videofile()` is using ffmpeg anyway. For example:

```py
# from the source of moviepy (ffmpeg_writer.py - line 80 onwards)
cmd = [
            get_setting("FFMPEG_BINARY"),
            '-y',
            '-loglevel', 'error' if logfile == sp.PIPE else 'info',
            '-f', 'rawvideo',
            '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
            '-s', '%dx%d' % (size[0], size[1]),
            '-pix_fmt', 'rgba' if withmask else 'rgb24',
            '-r', '%.02f' % fps,
            '-an', '-i', '-'
        ]

.... more codes

if threads is not None:
    cmd.extend(["-threads", str(threads)])
```