# Rendering videos too slow using Python MoviePY

Tags: python, multithreading, moviepy

The rendering of this 10 minute video on moviepy takes ~50 minutes.

```
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(videoClipArray, method='compose')
final_clip.write_videofile(videoName, fps=24, threads=12)
```

I know that increasing the thread count, and optimizing the fps will speed up my render speed as per this post:
[Concat videos too slow using Python MoviePY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413813/concat-videos-too-slow-using-python-moviepy/57614118#57614118)

My question is, should I expect the speed at which the video renders to scale linearly with the number of threads?

Example:
I currently have an AMD Ryzen 5 2600 6-Core & 12-Thread.
If I were to buy an AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3970X 32-Core, 64-Thread, could I expect a ~5x increase in speed (due to the ~5x increase in threads)? i.e. 10 minutes instead of 50 minutes of render time for the same video?

I know that using AWS or another cloud service is an option, but I would rather own my hardware if possible.

Comment: It's just not that simple.  There's not only CPU power to consider, but memory bandwidth and I/O bandwidth.  All of those videos are getting read from disk and written to disk, and disks are not infinitely fast.

Comment: I have a NVMe SSD with read/write up to 3,500/2,900MB/s so I considered I/O speeds a non-factor (if this is a bottle neck feel free to correct me).
I was also considering memory a non-factor (or at least not a bottle neck), as I have 16GB DDR4  running at 3200 MHz.

Comment: Probably right.  Have you done the math?  Do you know how much data you're shoving around here?

Comment: All videos are ~300MB in size and ~10 min long. I believe that the reason rendering is taking so long is due to the fact I'm using the moviepy CompositeVideoClip to add ImageClip and TextClip at multiple points throughout the video. I am also using a 1920x1080 resolution which contributes to the render time as well I'm sure

Comment: Are you transcoding?  A 10 minute H264 file won't fit in 300MB unless you have compressed it into oblivion.  Not that it really helps answer your quesstion...

Comment: No I don' t believe so. The codec is H.264 and bit rate is 2902 kbps

I am just moviepy's built inconcatenate_videoclips() function followed by the write_videofile() function & I don't believe this transcodes the file (especially since I just checked it's still H.264).

All of my videos that are around 10 minutes are also under 300MB