# How to add transitions between clips in moviepy?

Tags: python, video, concatenation, transition, moviepy

#### My current attempt:

This is my current code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *

clips = [VideoFileClip('a.mp4'), VideoFileClip('b.mp4'), VideoFileClip('c.mp4')]
transitioned_clips = [demo_clip.crossfadein(2) for demo_clip in clips]
for_delivery = concatenate_videoclips(transitioned_clips)
for_delivery.write_videofile(target_path, fps=clip.fps, bitrate='%dK' % (bitrate), threads=50, verbose=False, logger=None, preset='ultrafast')
```

I also tried using `CompositeVideoClip`, but:

1. It resulted in a completely black video.
2. Even for the completely black video it took 50 times longer to write the video file than for without transitions.

#### My current output:

My current output is a video with the 3 videos concatenated (*which is good*), but no transitions between the clips (*which is not good*).

#### My goal:

My goal is to add the `crossfadein` transition for 2 seconds between the clips and concatenate the clips into one video and output it.

In other words, I want it like (in order from left to right):

```
|        |      +       |        |      +       |        |
| clip 1 | transition 1 | clip 2 | transition 2 | clip 3 |
|        |      +       |        |      +       |        |
```

---

Is there anyway to have transitions? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this approach of manually setting the start time to handle the transitions.

```py
padding = 2

video_clips = [VideoFileClip('a.mp4'), VideoFileClip('b.mp4'), VideoFileClip('c.mp4')]

video_fx_list = [video_clips[0]]

idx = video_clips[0].duration - padding
for video in video_clips[1:]:
    video_fx_list.append(video.set_start(idx).crossfadein(padding))
    idx += video.duration - padding

final_video = CompositeVideoClip(video_fx_list)
final_video.write_videofile(target_path, fps=clip.fps) # add any remaining params
```

Edit:
Here's an attempt using `concatenate`:

```py
custom_padding = 2
final_video = concatenate(
    [
        clip1,
        clip2.crossfadein(custom_padding),
        clip3.crossfadein(custom_padding)
    ],
    padding=-custom_padding,
    method="chain"
)
final_video.write_videofile(target_path, fps=clip.fps) # add any remaining params
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer... But `CompositeVideoClip` seems to be much slower than `concatenate_videoclips`. It worked, but took 10x longer time that `concatenate_videoclips`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But the audio is disappearing, how do I keep the audio?

Comment: Thanks. It actually works. But speed is still slow. Anyway, in the coming days I will award you the bounty! Thanks very much for the answer!!

Comment: @U12-Forward consider this for speed-up ideas https://stackoverflow.com/q/56413813/9350720

Comment: I saw that one before, I am using all of the answers combined

Comment: Check my question, I am already using 50 threads

Comment: @U12-Forward I'm suggesting you to try something lower than 50

Comment: Oh sorry, I will try

Comment: It took 10 minutes to render a one minute long video... with 16 threads

Comment: WOW! I changed `method='compose'` to `method='chain` and now it only takes a minute and a half to render!!!! And it works! Thanks very much I will award the bounty.

Comment: @U12-Forward good point, updated the answer to reflect that

Comment: @U12-Forward thanks! Also, let's clean up the non-essential comments here (since the method change comment i the only one with useful information imo)

Comment: Hey @AbhinavMathur... Could you help me do a favor? How would I add music to the final output of the video? Thanks!

Comment: @U12-Forward https://stackoverflow.com/a/55920417

Comment: I am testing it now

Comment: That answer doesn't work, I saw maybe 5 other questions about this, they all don't work... I maybe would have to ask a new question?

Comment: @U12-Forward yes, that's what SO recommends

Comment: Ah Okay. Will do

Comment: [Adding music to \`VideoClip\` doesn't work - moviepy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72358229)

Comment: Could you help me with that?